# Failed because: Unable to locate file to upload but path is correct (Vimeo API)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vimeo, vimeo-api

I don't even know where to start with this one. I am using the Vimeo API to upload videos to vimeo. Sucesfully generated an acess token and I have permission to upload. However, when I specify my video to upload it, I get the error: "Failed because: Unable to locate file to upload" even though my path is correct :O

Here is the part if the code that is responsible for the upload:

> ```
> var uploadv = document.getElementById("uploadvideo");
>       uploadv.addEventListener("click", function() {
>
>         var Vimeo = require('./indextwo').Vimeo
>
>
> console.log('clicked');
>
>       
>
>
>       try {
>         var config = require('./example/config.json')
>       } catch (error) {
>         console.error('ERROR: For this example to run properly you must create an API app at ' +
>           'https://developer.vimeo.com/apps/new and set your callback url to ' +
>           '`http://localhost:8080/oauth_callback`.')
>         console.error('ERROR: Once you have your app, make a copy of `config.json.example` named ' +
>           '`config.json` and add your client ID, client secret and access token.')
>         process.exit()
>       }
>       
>       if (!config.access_token) {
>         throw new Error('You can not upload a video without configuring an access token.')
>       }
>       
>       // Instantiate the library with your client id, secret and access token (pulled from dev site)
>       var client = new Vimeo(config.client_id, config.client_secret, config.access_token)
>       
>       // Create a variable with a hard coded path to your file system
>       var filePath = '../testvideo.mp4'
>       
>       console.log('Uploading: ' + filePath)
>       
>       var params = {
>         'name': 'Vimeo API SDK test upload',
>         'description': "This video was uploaded through the Vimeo API's NodeJS SDK."
>       }
>       
>       client.upload(
>         filePath,
>         params,
>         function (uri) {
>           // Get the metadata response from the upload and log out the Vimeo.com url
>           client.request(uri + '?fields=link', function (error, body, statusCode, headers) {
>             if (error) {
>               console.log('There was an error making the request.')
>               console.log('Server reported: ' + error)
>               return
>             }
>       
>             console.log('"' + filePath + '" has been uploaded to ' + body.link)
>       
>             // Make an API call to edit the title and description of the video.
>             client.request({
>               method: 'PATCH',
>               path: uri,
>               params: {
>                 'name': 'Vimeo API SDK test edit',
>                 'description': "This video was edited through the Vimeo API's NodeJS SDK."
>               }
>             }, function (error, body, statusCode, headers) {
>               if (error) {
>                 console.log('There was an error making the request.')
>                 console.log('Server reported: ' + error)
>                 return
>               }
>       
>               console.log('The title and description for ' + uri + ' has been edited.')
>       
>               // Make an API call to see if the video is finished transcoding.
>               client.request(
>                 uri + '?fields=transcode.status',
>                 function (error, body, statusCode, headers) {
>                   if (error) {
>                     console.log('There was an error making the request.')
>                     console.log('Server reported: ' + error)
>                     return
>                   }
>       
>                   console.log('The transcode status for ' + uri + ' is: ' + body.transcode.status)
>                 }
>               )
>             })
>           })
>         },
>         function (bytesUploaded, bytesTotal) {
>           var percentage = (bytesUploaded / bytesTotal * 100).toFixed(2)
>          console.log(bytesUploaded, bytesTotal, percentage + '%')
>        },
>        function (error) {
>           console.log('Failed because: ' + error)
>        }
>       )
>     })
> ```

The problem I think is in the last part of the code:

```
function (bytesUploaded, bytesTotal) {
          var percentage = (bytesUploaded / bytesTotal * 100).toFixed(2)
         console.log(bytesUploaded, bytesTotal, percentage + '%')
       },
       function (error) {
          console.log('Failed because: ' + error)
       }
      )
```

If I can offer more parts of the code so you have a better idea, please let me know! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: again wondering if you eve got a solution for this...

Comment: Did you solve this issue? 
I have faced the same issue but didn't get any right solution to solve this, and finally I comes to know that the issue caused by its file size. Although I am doing this at my laravel project